# Creating an Android Studio Workspace on a USB Drive for multiple pc use

Tags: android, android-studio, workspace, usb-drive

I attempted installing android studio on my laptop and using my USB drive as a workspace so I can stay agile between work, school, and home computers with my projects. However when I try to load the workspace on another computer get usually get a slew of errors that I can't quote right now (will try to add later if necessary). Are there common errors in this process or is this the improper method to share an android workspace across multiple computers?

Comment: Use version control like Git, GitHub, Subversion, etc.

Comment: There is probably some path in the configuration that is specific to the computer where tou created the project. Like the SDK path. The easiest fix would be to use version control (like GIT). AndroidStudio will add some entries to the ignore file to automaticly avoid that problem.

Comment: Thanks. Googling what I asked did not bring up what was needed. That was the information I needed. 

https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/vcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is as commented, to use version control. Below is a linked tutorial to using version control for android studio

https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/vcs